# TCP SACK fix for Ubuntu 16.04 kernel version 4.15.0-1021-gcp

Tags: ubuntu, linux-kernel, security

I have server in Google Cloud, running Ubuntu 16.04 with kernel version 4.15.0-1021-gcp.

A fix for some vulnerability fix was [recently released](https://access.redhat.com/security/vulnerabilities/tcpsack).
I have question about that: do I need to update my kernel? If so, how should I go about it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to upgrade your kernel; the TCP SACK vulnerabilities were fixed in [version 4.15.0-1034.36~16.04.1](http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/pool/main/l/linux-gcp/linux-gcp_4.15.0-1034.36~16.04.1/changelog) of the Ubuntu kernel image for GCP on 16.04.

To do so,

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
```

should be sufficient, followed by a reboot. If you only want to upgrade the kernel,

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt install linux-image-gcp
```

will upgrade the kernel to the latest ABI, which currently will ensure you get the latest kernel. If you have other kernel-related packages installed, you may need to upgrade them too; in particular, `linux-headers-gcp`, `linux-modules-extra-gcp`, `linux-tools-gcp`.

If you care about keeping your system secure, you should really upgrade all the installed packages anyway; within a single release, great care is taken so that `apt upgrade` is safe. You’d have to plan for downtime here since the TCP SACK upgrade involves a reboot, so you might as well upgrade everything else; do a test upgrade in your staging environment first.

To verify that the kernel you’re running after rebooting is fixed, the only sure-fire way is to find a reliable exploit, try it against your system and see whether it panics. If it doesn’t, the kernel is fixed; if it does, the kernel isn’t fixed.

(I don’t know whether a fix is available in [Livepatch](https://ubuntu.com/livepatch).)

Answer (score 0):

if you have the -generic kernel instead of gcp, its fixed in [linux_4.15.0-54.58](http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/pool/main/l/linux/linux_4.15.0-54.58/changelog)